# Linux streaming server with playlist

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming

everybody would like to help you, I need indication of a free software for streaming video, more accurate meet some needs

A transmission enabling accurate real-time
create playlist for playback (for when not live)

able to transmit live remotely.

some good streaming video for linux requires a webcam or video files is within the own server to stream live, broadcast remotely accurate

my dedicated server will take charge of Transmit, and will get the client computer that will be in Brazil, I need remotely, so far not found it'm hoping you indicate me some good

obs: to be a free software

if someone can indicate'm very grateful, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The only big robust free software I know of is red5:

http://www.red5.org/

You may also want to look into the NGINX streaming module. I played with it for a little bit and it worked great. I never tested it with a high load though:

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

However, where I work we use Wowza. Its not free but man is it so easy and so good:

http://www.wowza.com/

So the thing about all these is I have never done what you are saying. I've used all three of these for live streaming and they all will work but I have never done a simulated live streaming like what you are looking for. I know Wowza can do it, I would be shocked if Red5 couldnt and I have no idea about Nginx. Its not the best answer but hopefully it gives you some options.

I know VLC has some playlist to streaming abilities so if anything you can use VLC from the client side and then just push it to Red5. Hopefully this points you in the right direction!